# SignalR: Negotiation works, but messages are not being sent (.NET/Angular)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I try to get a very basic SignalR example to work that is based on [Microsoft's tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and the Weatherforecast .NET/Angular SPA created by Visual Studio as a basis as this is the same type of project I later want to use SignalR with. [The entire source code is at GitHub.](https://github.com/Aileron79/SignalR-Demo)

It looks as if the handshake/negotiation works and a websocket connection is established - but no messages are flowing there. This is what the Chrome Developer Tools show:
[image]

I have the feeling I overlooked something minor, but I'm struggling to see what it could be.

I started by adjusting the `Program.cs` file, this is the relevant code:

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

...

app.UseCors();
  
//app.MapHub<ProgressHub>("/progressHub");
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ProgressHub>("/progresshub"); // Map the hub URL here
});

app.Run();
```

Note that MS suggests to use `app.MapHub<ProgressHub>("/progressHub");` but som resources suggested to use `app.UseEndpoints` instead. It doesn't seem to make any difference. Also, I tried using `app.UseWebSockets();` but that did not change anything either. Also, I made sure to enable CORS.

This is the controller method I added which is supposed to send messages on the SignalR channel:

```
[HttpPost("startProcess")]
public async Task<IActionResult> StartProcess()
{
    // Some logic to start the long-running process
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        // Report progress to the client
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveProgressUpdate", $"Step {i + 1} completed.");
    }

    return Ok("[]");
}
```

When stepping through the code, no exceptions are thrown, the code runs without any issues. On the Angular client side I have installed the signalr package and created a service:

```
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: HubConnection;
  private progressSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:44429/progresshub')
      .build();

    this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveProgressUpdate', (progressMessage: string) => {
      this.progressSubject.next(progressMessage);
    });

    this.hubConnection.start().catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  getProgressUpdates() {
    return this.progressSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Now I use that service in my SignalR component, but the progressUpdates array remains empty:

```
export class SignalRComponent implements OnInit {
  progressUpdates: string[] = [];
  _httpClient: HttpClient;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private signalRService: SignalRService) {
    this._httpClient = httpClient;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signalRService.getProgressUpdates().subscribe((progressMessage: string) => {
      this.progressUpdates.push(progressMessage);
    });
  }

  startProcess() {
    this.httpClient.post('https://localhost:44429/weatherforecast/startProcess', {}).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Also, I have turned on the WebSocket Protocol in Windows as this was suggested on SO as well:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download your repo and change the `proxy.conf.js` file like below. And it works  well. You can according your needs to change other settings.

I also enable the client side logging so that we can make the connection is established.

**Test Result**

[image]

**proxy.conf.js**

```
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:50822';



const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/progresshub"
   ],
    target: target, 
    changeOrigin: true,  
    logLevel: "debug",
    rejectUnauthorzied: true, 
    secure: false,            
    strictSSL: true,          
    withCredentials: true,
    ws: true
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

**signal-r.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } from '@microsoft/signalr';
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: HubConnection;
  private progressSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:44429/progresshub', signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets | signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling).configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
      .build();

    this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveProgressUpdate', (progressMessage: string) => {
      this.progressSubject.next(progressMessage);
    });
    this.hubConnection.start().catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  getProgressUpdates() {
    return this.progressSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I just posted the same answer to my own question - I was not quick enough. It indeed is a problem with the proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the culprit, it is the ASP proxy which per default configuration does not allow websocket connections. The `PROXY_CONFIG` const in `proxy.conf.js` needs to be set like this:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: ["/progresshub"], 
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    ws: true // Enable WebSocket proxying
  },
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]
```

The configuration needs to be split into separate contexts for the weatherforecast (or any other) API and the websocket as the Keep-Alive headers are not allowed for websocket connections.

Credit goes to [this post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/y1mi6p/how_to_enable_signalr_for_angular_dev_server/).

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, I am also working on this, [glad you can solve it by yourself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5edq.png) .